# fancyvrb error when using macros in Verbatim option

Tags: errors, verbatim, fancyvrb

When using the `firstnumber=...` option in the `Verbatim` environment of `fancyvrb`, I found strange behavioral difference involved with macros. The following has no problem:

```
\def\foo{2}
\begin{Verbatim}[firstnumber=\foo]
line 2
\end{Verbatim}
```

but the following gives `! Missing number, treated as zero` error

```
\def\foo{last}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},firstnumber=\foo]
line 2
\end{Verbatim}
```

(The `commandchars=\\\{\}` option makes no difference.) What would be the reason? I found a walk-around of using `\fvset{firstnumber=last}` if I want (or replacing `\foo` with `last` explicitly), but I would like to learn.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\fvset{numbers=left}
\begin{Verbatim}
line 1
\end{Verbatim}

\def\foo{2}
\begin{Verbatim}[firstnumber=\foo]
line 2
\end{Verbatim}

%% problem HERE
\def\foo{last}
\begin{Verbatim}[firstnumber=\foo]
line 3
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

(I didn't write `commandchars=\\\{\}` because it makes no difference.) The error message is:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   l
l.18 line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code is defined in `fancyvrb.sty` where the `firstnumber` key is defined like the following:

```
\define@key{FV}{firstnumber}[auto]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}\def\@tempb{auto}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \def\FV@SetLineNo{%
      \c@FancyVerbLine\FV@CodeLineNo
      \advance\c@FancyVerbLine\m@ne}%
  \else
    \def\@tempb{last}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
      \let\FV@SetLineNo\relax
    \else
      \def\FV@SetLineNo{\c@FancyVerbLine#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
```

Here a reduced version with the essential parts only:

```
\define@key{FV}{firstnumber}[auto]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{last}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \let\FV@SetLineNo\relax
  \else
    \def\FV@SetLineNo{\c@FancyVerbLine#1}%
  \fi}
```

`\@tempa` is defined to the value of the parameter to `firstnumber` (`#1`), `\@tempb` is defined to be `last`. Now let's consider both cases:

1. `firstnumber=last`: In this case we have `\def\@tempa{last}` which is basically the same as `\def\@tempb{last}`. When `\ifx\@tempa\@tempb` is expanded, the two tokens following `\ifx` are compared. If they are control sequences, both are considered equal if they are the same primitive command, or have the same parameter text, the same replacement text as well as the same modifiers like `\long`. The parameters are the same here for `\@tempa` and `\@tempb` (they don't have any), their replacement text is also the same (`last`), and any modifiers are also missing for both. In this case the test for `\ifx` is considerd positive and the following assignment `\let\FV@SetLineNo\relax` is the final expansion. (At some point `\FV@SetLineNo` is called to set the line number for the new block. The definition `\relax` doesn't do any changes then.)
2. `firstnumber=\foo`: Now the first parameter is `\foo` and the definition for `\@tempa` becomes `\def\@tempa{\foo}` while `\@tempb` is still `last`. As `\ifx` doesn't do a full expansion when comparing both macros, the replacement texts to be compared are now `\foo` and `last` which are *not* the same as before. Accordingly, the result is negative and the `\else` part becomes the final expansion. Again, `\FV@SetLineNo` is defined but now we find the assignment `\c@FancyVerbLine#1` in it, which sets the (integer) counter `\c@FancyVerbLine` to the value of the first parameter `\foo`. At some point this macro is expanded leading to an assignment that doesn't start with a number but with the `l`from `last`. And this is exactly the error you see reported in the error message.

That's also the explanation why different values for `commandchars` don't have any effect here, and why `\def\foo{2}` on the other hand works fine.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your clear and detailed answer! So the problem will be gone if `\expandafter` is used somewhere properly.